# Delay before apply object changes (similar like setNeedsDisplay)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have object with properties and when I change some of properties, I do a lot of calculations. If I change one property, then another, calculations execute 2 times. I want do all calculations 1 time. I see 3 solution:

1. Make method `commit`. But I don't wanna do excess methods.
2. Make method for change all properties. The same cause why I don't wanna do this. And what to do if I will have much more properties in future.
3. Make delay after delay commit changes. I really do not know what consequences this may turn into. Something like this:

.

```
@interface TestObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) float x;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float y;
@end

@implementation TestObject
{
    BOOL flag;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        flag = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setX:(float)x
{
    _x = x;
    [self delayCommit];
}

- (void)setY:(float)y
{
    _y = y;
    [self delayCommit];
}

- (void)delayCommit
{
    if(flag == NO){
        flag = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(commit) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)commit
{
    flag = NO;
    NSLog(@"Do a lot of calculations....");
}

@end
```

Is third solution good practice? I want simple interface, I don't want excess methods.

Comment: What do you mean with "But I don't wanna do excess methods."? Also, what is the use case? Will all the properties be set by a user? Give us more info as to how the properties are changed"

Comment: I don't want change interface of class. Create method 'commit' is solution, I know. But maybe there is another way to do this class. Like method 3. You can change 1 property or 2, don't matter. Complex method must call just 1 time.

Comment: ok then check my answer and tell me whether it's what you were thinking of

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a behavior like that, you should then have a timer that every `N` seconds, checks if any of the properties are changed, and does the computations. Something like:

```
- (void)setX:(float)x
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_mySem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        _x = x;
        flag = YES;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_mySem);
    });  
}

- (void)setY:(float)y
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_mySem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        _y = y;
        flag = YES;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_mySem);
    });  
}

- (void)updateCycle
{        
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_mySem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        if(flag){
            flag = NO;
            NSLog(@"Do a lot of calculations....");
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_mySem);
    });           
}
```

In your `init` method you would have to initialise the timer and the semaphore with

```
_mySem = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:N 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateCycle) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

The way to use it would then just be:

```
[object setX:4.5f];
[object setY:0.3f];
```

Comment: My eyes!!!) I see you have a lot of experience with semaphores. It's cool! But my 3 solution for me much better. You solution with timers, it's not good. I have about 100 elements) Maybe I told not much that I must, sorry. I upvote yours answer, it's interesting solution) I think not for me

Comment: Just be aware that your solution 3 is not thread safe, so make sure you always make the calls from the same thread! :) With my edited solution it should all work fine. It shouldn't be a problem to keep the lock on the semaphore, as all the object state updates are done on a secondary thread (so you'll never block the main thread)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many properties you have, this may work for you instead:

```
- (void)setX:(float)x y:(float)y
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
    [self commit];
}
```

Here, you set more than one property with one method call. You know you have all the values you need, so you can call `commit` directly.

Comment: I have 5 properties) This code example. And properties will be more

Comment: That's not too many to put into a single method. If you are changing all five values at the same time, this makes it easy. If you are only changing two or three values at a time and it varies which ones you change at a given time, that takes more effort.

Comment: I understand you. I look in future, now I have only 5 properties. I'm planing make additionally 4 properties. I want beautiful interface) What you think about my third solution?

Comment: In your example, solution 3 seems to work, but it's not something I would do. Simply put, the code is fragile and inflexible. What if you get into a scenario where you need to set X twice, then Y once, then perform calculations? Or if you only need to set Y without setting X?

Comment: It's all ok, try. You can change X value 100 times in cycle) Commit will call just 1 time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to try to be too fancy with delayed commits (unless you really have to) and to use commit as a separate call and perform your long calculation in a separate thread, e.g.:

```
- (void)setX:(float)x
{
    _x = x;
}

- (void)setY:(float)y
{
    _y = y;
}

- (void)commitChanges
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // ... Long calculations go here ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      // ... Once you done with your long calculation, put your UI code here
      // ... (e.g. display results of your calculation in text box)
    });
   });
}
```

then from your main code will look like:

```
[obj setX:123.0f];
[obj setY:345.0f];
[obj commitChanges];
```

Comment: Why delayed commits is bad?

Comment: I'm not saying that it is bad, what I'm trying to say is that you need a good reason to use it, otherwise not only your code becomes more complex, but also troubleshooting and debugging your code will be more difficult.